# how can we use native methods of array in gpu js like length push pop. It gives me an error of unexpected expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, gpu.js

```
const A = [9, 2];
const test = gpu
.createKernel(function (A) {
        return A.length;
})
.setOutput([1]);
console.log(test(A));
```

ERROR:
throw this.astErrorOutput('Unexpected expression', ast);
^

Error: Unexpected expression on line 1, position 0:
A.length
at WebGLFunctionNode.astErrorOutput (E:\ProData\G\node_modules\gpu.js\src\backend\function-node.js:972:12)
at WebGLFunctionNode.getMemberExpressionDetails (E:\ProData\G\node_modules\gpu.js\src\backend\function-node.js:1305:24)
at WebGLFunctionNode.astMemberExpression (E:\ProData\G\node_modules\gpu.js\src\backend\web-gl\function-node.js:1051:14)
at WebGLFunctionNode.astGeneric (E:\ProData\G\node_modules\gpu.js\src\backend\function-node.js:944:23)
at WebGLFunctionNode.astReturnStatement (E:\ProData\G\node_modules\gpu.js\src\backend\web-gl\function-node.js:168:18)
at WebGLFunctionNode.astGeneric (E:\ProData\G\node_modules\gpu.js\src\backend\function-node.js:900:23)
at WebGLFunctionNode.astFunction (E:\ProData\G\node_modules\gpu.js\src\backend\web-gl\function-node.js:116:12)
at WebGLFunctionNode.astFunctionExpression (E:\ProData\G\node_modules\gpu.js\src\backend\function-node.js:1019:17)
at WebGLFunctionNode.astGeneric (E:\ProData\G\node_modules\gpu.js\src\backend\function-node.js:898:23)
at WebGLFunctionNode.toString (E:\ProData\G\node_modules\gpu.js\src\backend\function-node.js:324:32)